# How to add the sum total of 2 columns in an SQL query

Tags: sql, sum, addition

Here is a simple example of my problem

I have 2 tables

table1 has a column called price (of numeric data type) and 3 rows with the values of 2, 3.5 and 8

table2 also has a column called price (of numeric data type) and 3 rows with the values of 4.3, 6.5 and 9

I want to add up all the rows in each column (so total for table1 will be 13.5, and table2 will be 19.8) and then add those together (so the grand total will be 33.3)

How do I do this in an SQL query so that it returns 33.3?

Comment: Which sql language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION to combine rows from two different tables:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS GrandTotal
FROM (
    SELECT price FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT price FROM table2
) AS x
```

Comment: you'd probably want `UNION ALL` so that you don't delete duplicate records

Answer (score 0):

One method is subqueries:

```
select sum(price from table1) + sum(price from table2)
```

Most databases do not require a `from` clause; some want something like `from dual`.